# SharePoint custom web part jQuery is "undefined"

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010, migration, sharepoint-2013, web-parts

I am trying to move a custom web app (contacts list) from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013. The contact list works by using jQuery to show a name with a picture, and after clicking on the dark gray bar reveals the rest of the contact information like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVtOj.jpg

The list works perfectly in sharepoint 2010 but not in 2013. Here is the code that seems to be breaking:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery('#' + '<%= firstpane.ClientID %>' + " div.menu_head").click(function () 
{
jQuery(this).css({ backgroundImage: "" }).next("table.menu_body").slideToggle(100).siblings("table.menu_body").slideUp("fast");
jQuery(this).siblings().css({ backgroundImage: "" });
});

</script>
```

In sharepoint 2010 when the contact bar is clicked, the table of information is shown perfectly. In 2013, the contact bar is shown but when clicked does not toggle. When I run this in developer tools I get an error stating:

in IE:
    SCRIPT5009: 'jQuery' is undefined

in chrome: 
    Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

If I try and change jQuery to $ then I get the same error but instead it says $ is not defined. I checked the permissions of the jQuery file in sharepoint and it says the file is there and accessible. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Roger

Comment: Try adding the Jquery library and wrap all in `document.ready`

Comment: How would I add the jQuery library? I'm not a native jQuery user. I tried to wrap the code in document.ready but it didnt seem to make a difference.

Comment: http://sympmarc.com/2011/05/03/adding-jquery-to-a-sharepoint-page-step-one-always/ see this link.

Comment: Do I just copy paste that into my code? Or do I need to edit the src to match my files

Comment: Edit the src and match it with you Jquery files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a visual webpart and add all js file which you need with the this code

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Type csType = this.GetType();
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

        String jQueryURL0 = path+ "_layouts/15/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js";
        if (!cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(csType, "jquery.js"))
        {
            cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(csType, "jquery.js", jQueryURL0);
        }

    }
```

and add jquery link to your webpart

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="jqgrid" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/15/jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

Or add the link to jquery to the masterpage directly

Comment: Just adding the ScriptLink should be enough... no need to register it on page load.